# how to make a relationship between 3 tables using the Join() method and using two values ​as a rule Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-4

I trying to join 3 tables and I need to compare two values to make the first relationship, and make the second relationship based on that.
But I don't know how to use the `Join()` method to do that.

I need to return value when `PRTCL_BLQ` and `SQ_BLQ` of `TB_TABLE_1` is equals `PRTCL_BLQ_VL` and `SQ_BLQ_VLR` of `TB_TABLE_2`.

After that I need to compare the `VARAJUIZO_BLQ_VLR` of returns with `VARAJUIZO` of `TB_TABLE_3` and than return the `NM_VARAJUIZO` and `TRIBUNAL` values.

I have these 3 tables:

**First table:**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data.Model
{
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 public partial class TB_TABLE_1
 {
    public decimal Attr1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Attr2 { get; set; }
    public string Attr3 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Attr4 { get; set; }
    public string PRTCL_BLQ { get; set; }
    public string SQ_BLQ { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**Second table:**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data.Model
{
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 public partial class TB_TABLE_2
 {
    public decimal Attr1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Attr2 { get; set; }
    public string Attr3 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Attr4 { get; set; }
    public string PRTCL_BLQ_VLR { get; set; }
    public string SQ_BLQ_VLR { get; set; }
    public string VARAJUIZO_BLQ_VLR { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**Third table:**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Data.Model
{
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 public partial class TB_TABLE_3
 {
    public string VARAJUIZO { get; set; }
    public string NM_VARAJUIZO { get; set; }
    public string TRIBUNAL { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
return db.TB_TABLE_1
          .Join(TB_TABLE_2,
                tb1_prtcl => tb1_prtcl.PRTCL_BLQ,
                tb2_prtcl => tb2_prtcl.PRTCL_BLQ_VLR
                {}) //I don't know how to compare the 2 values (PRTCL_BLQ and SQ_BLQ) and continue that to join the third_table =(
          .Where(x => x.Attr1 == attr1 &&
                      x.Attr2 == attr2 &&
                      x.Attr3 == attr3)
          .ToList()
          .Select(x => new ReturnClass
           {
             Value1 = x.Attr1
             Value2 = x.Attr2
             Value3 = x.Attr3
             Prtcl = x.PRTCL_BLQ
             Sq = x.SQ_BLQ
           }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: No PKs! I guess a join will work on a string.